# Display a count field from a group by statement in a barplot / Axis formatting

Tags: python, bar-chart, pandas-groupby

I have the results of a group by statement

```
display(df.groupby(['originating_system_id'])['state'].count().reset_index(name='count').sort_values(['count'], ascending=False))
```

Output

```
originating_system_id   count
_________________________________
RBCL                11607
YBAU                2743
TWEU                2638
TWAU                846
VOIX                5
0                   1
```

I would like to produce a barplot showing `originating_system_id`   on the `x axis` and the `counts` of each on the `y axis`.

```
df_BarPlot = df.groupby(['originating_system_id'])['state'].count()
sns.barplot(x='originating_system_id',y='count',data=df_BarPlot)
```

1. I'm not sure how to reference the count column in the dataframe.
2. is there a way to ensure all the `originating_system_id` field names display in the resulting graph?
3. On my other the plots the numeric values are displaying in scientific notation. Can we introduce an automatic format for barplots and distplot which shows numeric fields as as say 1000, 000, 000 etc.

Comment: On point 1: I guess this question is how to parse the results of any group by column to any seaborn graph i.e. jointplot, barplot etc boxplot,

On point 2: This is to ensure long field values are displayed without being squashed together. ie.the graph autofits the values so all strings appear

Comment: On Point 1: I can assign to another dataframe but would like to avoid this an do it in one line of code.

Comment: Do you want to replace the scientific notation to show all numbers?

Comment: yes, thant would be good. It's defaulting

Comment: Which plots are you trying to do?

Comment: distplot. I have a number of other dataframes which have values from 10 to 500 000 000. I'd just like to force seaborn to format specific way.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think this is what you need.

Comment: Fantastic, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the count plot, you can use [`sns.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) on the original `DataFrame` without `grouping`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(x='originating_system_id', data=df)
```

---

As for the scientific notation, you can use [`matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tick = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False, useMathText=True)

'''
tick.set_powerlimits() represent the limits you want your label to show at so in this case 
the minimum is 10^0 and the maximum is set to 10^100 
(It won't turn your labels to scientific notation if your max data point is less than 10^100)
'''
tick.set_powerlimits((0,100)) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick)
sns.distplot(... , ax=ax)
```